# Which set checkpointing interval (ms)?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

everyone.
Please help me. 
I write apache flink streraming job, which reads json messages from apache kafka (500-1000 messages in seconds), deserialize them in POJO and performs some operations (filter-keyby-process-sink). I used RocksDB state backend with ExactlyOnce semantic. But I do not understand which checkpointing interval I need set?
Some forums peoples write mostly 1000 or 5000 ms.
I tried to set interval 10ms, 100ms, 500ms, 1000ms, 5000ms. I have not noticed any differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two factors argue in favor of a reasonably small checkpoint interval:

(1) If you are using a sink that does two-phase transactional commits, such as Kafka or the StreamingFileSink, then those transactions will only be committed during checkpointing. Thus any downstream consumers of the output of your job will experience latency that is governed by the checkpoint interval.

Note that you will not experience this delay with Kafka unless you have taken all of the steps required to have exactly-once semantics, end-to-end. This means that you must set `Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE` in the Kafka producer, and set the `isolation.level` in downstream consumers to `read_committed`. And if you are doing this, you should also increase `transaction.max.timeout.ms` beyond the default (which is 15 minutes). See the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-producers-and-fault-tolerance) for more.

(2) If your job fails and needs to recover from a checkpoint, the inputs will be rewound to the offsets recorded in the checkpoint, and processing will resume from there. If the checkpoint interval is very long (e.g., 30 minutes), then your job may take quite a while to catch back up to the point where it is once again processing events in near real-time (assuming you are processing live data).

On the other hand, checkpointing does add some overhead, so doing it more often than necessary has an impact on performance.

Comment: thanks David. 
I understand p.2, but I do not understand p.1. 
I have this structure schema: Kafka #1 - My Flink JOB - Kafka #2, and I use 5s checkpointing interval, and I have not got any latency, all messages from Kafka #1 instantly to record in Kafka #2 without any latency

Comment: I have expanded my answer. I assume you haven't fully set up exactly once for Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the points described by @David, my suggestion is also to use the following function to configure the checkpoint time:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(milliseconds)
```

This way, you guarantee that your job will be able to make some progress in case the state gets bigger than planned or the storage where the checkpoints are made is slow.

I recommend reading the Flink documentation on [Tuning Checkpointing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/state/large_state_tuning.html#tuning-checkpointing) to better understand these scenarios.